# Converting pandas data frame to dictionary in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

My pandas dataframe (df):

```
Pattern      Support

Bread         4
Milk          4
Bread,Milk    4
```

My code:

```
x = df.set_index('Pattern').to_dict()
print(x)
```

Output of my code:

```
{'Support':{'MILK': 4,'BREAD':4, 'BREAD,MILK':4}}
```

Expected Output:

```
{'MILK': 4,'BREAD':4, 'BREAD,MILK':4}
```

I do not want the name of the second column 'Support' to be the main key, just want to get the elements and the count as in the expected output. Is there any pythonic (python 3.5) way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Packed too much in one line, but it will give you what you want.

```
list(df.set_index('Pattern').to_dict().values()).pop()
```

Comment: It worked!! can you explain what does pop() function do here? @Hun